# load file in package class, no package in import

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my problem, I created a package that contains a class, this one is a word parser, in this package I created a json containing a list of words. This file is called `fr.json`.

The problem is that when I import the class with the command `from bin.Parser.parser import Parser` and I create the parser object it loads the file into the folder where I imported the class and not into the packages where the class is located.

I could specify the direction with "os.path", but, if I want to move my package and reuse it for another project I am obliged to specify again the link from where "fr.json" is located.

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, language):
        self.language = language + ".json"
        words_and_caracters = json.load(open('self.language'))
        self.LIST_WORD = words_and_caracters["LIST_WORD"]
        self.LIST_CARACTER = words_and_caracters["LIST_CARACTER"]
    ....
```

The tree structure:

```
├── Parser
│   ├── fr.json
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── parser.py
├── test.py
```

Import in test:

```
from Parser.parser import Parser

parser = Parser('fr')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following snippet. It generate path to the directory containing your package (dynamically) and then, append the filename.

```
import os    
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, language):
        file_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.language = os.path.join(file_dir_path, "{}.json".format(language))
        words_and_caracters = json.load(open('self.language'))
        self.LIST_WORD = words_and_caracters["LIST_WORD"]
        self.LIST_CARACTER = words_and_caracters["LIST_CARACTER"]
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. just a little correction if someone's looking for the same solution, if you know changed it is 3 lines if there was an error in open a string instead of the variable, and I had to add a'/' after {}.json.
<code>
 file_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.language = os.path.join(file_dir_path + "/{}.json".format(language))
        words_and_caracters = json.load(open(self.language))
</code>
@szymon

Comment: Better approach is to add comma `,` instead of `+` (i've make a typo) - so I've edited an answer.